# tmux script not creating 5th pane

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

I am working on the following script for setting up a tmux window with a very specific pane layout. For reasons I can't figure out, it isn't creating the final pane...

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d -s foo 'htop'
tmux rename-window 'Foo'
tmux select-window -t foo:0
tmux split-window -v 'tail -f logfile1.log'
tmux resize-pane -U 7
tmux split-window -h 'tail -f logfile2.log'
tmux resize-pane -U 7
tmux resize-pane -R 23
tmux select-pane -t 1
tmux split-window -v 'tail -f logfile3.log'
tmux select-pane -t 2
tmux split-window -h 'df -h'
tmux -2 attach-session -t foo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In tmux, if you pass a command when create window,  When the shell command completes, the window closes.  It behaves same for panes.

In your script, the other panes show because the command/processes are not finished yet (htop, tail -f). To test it, you can change the `df -h` into `df -h && sleep 20`.  Then you will see the pane for 20s.

There is a window option `remain-on-exit`, if you set it, the window/pane remains after the command execution finished. The pane/window will be marked "deactived/dead". You can re-active it by command `respawn-window` or `respawn-pane`

If you want it, add this line after your `tmux select-window....`:

```
tmux set-window-option remain-on-exit on
```